# problem with timer animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, timer, uiimageview

here is what I wanna do http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD3MTTPaK98
I have done the part where an image appears at a random position but then it become hard for me. I don't wanna use UIKit Animations because I use a  timer to animate like :imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y); but I can't animate more than one image at once I don't know why ? How can I solve this please

here is my code:

```
-(void) onTimer {


UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];


[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

[imageView release];

ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;

X=(240-ix)/230;
Y=(160-iy)/230;
coteA=(240-ix);
coteB=(160-iy);
angleDeRotation=atan(coteB/coteA);
if(ix>250||0>iy>320){
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleDeRotation+3.14);
}
else{
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleDeRotation);
}
}



-(void)onTimer2{
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
```

Comment: You can use cocos2d instead...

Comment: no way, I 'll never use cocos 2D

Comment: why not its the easiest way to go and you can still use the cocoa-touch objects in your scene.

Comment: no I have start my game without using cocos 2d. I don't like cocos 2d

Comment: I know exactly what is cocos 2d, but I don't wanna use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are not posting all of your code here, so I have to guess.

Are you creating imageView in `onTimer` and then trying to move "them" in `onTimer2`?

If YES, then

Because you are always setting the `imageView` var to the latest imageView you created in `onTimer` method, when you trying move the `imageView` in `onTimer2` method, you are only moving the latest one you created.

In order to move every imageView you've created, you'd better have a `for loop` in your `onTimer2` method.

In additional, you'd better make a NSMutableArray to save all your imageViews, or you can use `imageView.tag` to get your imageView again without having to create an NSMutableArray and release it later.

Here is an example how to use NSMutableArray to save and read all of your imageViews:

Add this to your class's `.h` file:

```
NSMutableArray *views;
NSMutableArray *XArray;
NSMutableArray *YArray;
```

Edit your `.m` file:

```
...
    //Create an array some where in your class:
    views = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
    XArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
    YArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
...

- (void)onTimer {
    [XArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(240.0f - ix)/230.0f]];
    [YArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(160.0f - iy)/230.0f]];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [views addObject:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

//Read:
- (void)onTimer2 {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
         UIImageView *imageView = [views objectAtIndex:i];
         CGFloat X = [[XArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
         CGFloat Y = [[YArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
         CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
    }
} 

- (void)dealloc {
    ...
    [views release];
    [XArray release];
    [YArray release];
    ...
}
```

Or you can use `imageView.tag` like this:

Add this to your class's `.h` file:

```
NSInteger imageViewCount;
```

Edit your `.m` file:

```
...
#define kImageViewFirstTag       10000
...

...
    //reset the count some where in your class if needed
    imageViewCount = 0;
...

- (void)onTimer {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [views addObject:imageView];
    imageView.tag = kImageViewFirstTag + imageViewCount;
    imageViewCount ++;
    [imageView release];
}


//Read:
- (void)onTimer2 {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < imageViewCount; i++) {
         UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kImageViewFirstTag + i];
         CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
    }
}
```

The two code are compiled by brain, correct me if there is any mistype.

**The first way is recommended, because it has better performance.**

Comment: I use your code with the array and look what happen there is a problem(I took a video of what happen):http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMIdMMWGSvQ

Comment: What is the problem? All of the images moving to the same direction? If you use the same logic to move every image view, of course they will move to the same direction. That's what you need to work on. Set different X & Y for different imageView for example.

Comment: The problem is that :an imageView is created at a random position then it moves to a specific direction then another imageView is created and it goes to a specific direction, but the previous imageView follows the same direction of the new one. I wanted that every imageView created follow its direction without changing it's direction. Please help me

Comment: Because your X and Y in onTimer2 method is always set to every imageView. That's why they are moving to the same direction. You should use different X and Y for different imageView. Maybe do not use the member ivar X and Y but calculate them for each imageView in the for loop.

Comment: how can I do this please ? I don't really understand

Comment: Would you please tell me how did you calculate the X and Y used in onTimer2 method? You can post the code here and I will give you some advice if I can. :)

Comment: it is in my code that I've posted: ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;

X=(240-ix)/230;
Y=(160-iy)/230;

Comment: Sorry, I missed that code. I've just edited the first way in my answer. Hope it helps. If it dose, please vote up and accept this answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your ivar `imageView` each time `-onTimer` is called. You should probably put each created imageview in an array or a set, or you could depending on your view structure iterate over `self.view.subviews`.